# Eigendecomposition question: obvious probably, but having trouble seeing it

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is a $2×2$ matrix, $S$ is the $2×2$ matrix where the columns are the two eigenvectors of $A$ and $M$ is the $2×2$ matrix with the two eigenvalues along the diagonal and zeros elsewhere. I am reading that by the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we have the following identity:
$$AS=SM$$
Why is that true? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_1,v_2 $ be your eigenvectors.  We can write down the matrix $S$ with $v_1,v_2 $ as columns.

If you write $S=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{bmatrix}$ then $AS=\begin{bmatrix} Av_1 & Av_2 \end{bmatrix}$,

on the other side $M=\begin{bmatrix} m_1 & 0  \\ 0 & m_2   \end{bmatrix}$ then
$\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} m_1 & 0  \\ 0 & m_2   \end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix} m_1 v_1  &  m_2v_2   \end{bmatrix}$.

So the   equation means $\begin{bmatrix} Av_1 & Av_2 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} m_1 v_1  &  m_2v_2   \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you. That is it. I found this link that basically shows your first inequality in the section called Right-multiplication: combination of columns                         https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/visualizing-matrix-multiplication-as-a-linear-combination/

Comment: You are welcome. We can always make operations on blocks inside matrices when dimensions for operations are  appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The diagonalisation of $A$ is $SMS^{-1}$. Right-multiplying by $S$ gives $AS=SM$.

(This only works if $A$ is diagonalisable  in the first place.)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I did not clarify, what I am reading starts with AS=SM and then goes on to show what you start with. I am reading here https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/the-linear-algebra-view-of-the-fibonacci-sequence-4e81f78935a3,   about 1/5 of the way down the page. They say that "By the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we have the following identity:"  and I don't see it by definition.